# Weird Layout Microsoft Word (on MacOS 11.4)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2019

I just opened MSWord for the first time in a few weeks and the layout seems to have changed and I don't know how to change it back:

[image: Main page]

There seem to be no margin between the first line of the document and the top of the page.
I tried fixing that using the Layout/margin menu, but it's set on normal:

[image: Layout & Margin Menu]

Even when opening a normal .docx document started in Google docs, Words shows this weird layout.
Do you have any idea on how can I revert this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT simply means that white spaces are hidden. Show them, put your cursor on the top of the page, then double-click when you see "Double click to see white space"

[image: White spaces - hide/view]